# Align two forms next to each other

Tags: html, forms

I have two forms in html and i want to align their buttons next to each other. Unfortunately I've tried to merge them but then they don't work properly. Is their any way to that i can achieve that if possible without css?

Below is my code:

```
<form action="lorhs.php" method="GET" name="FormPage">
    <button type="submit" id="backwards" <?php echo ($page == 1) ? "disabled" : ""; ?> style="float: left;" value="<?php echo $page-1; ?>" name="page">Prev</button>
    <button type="submit" id="forward" <?php echo ($page == ceil($row['0']/25)) ? "disabled" : ""; ?> style="float: left;" value="<?php echo $page+1; ?>" name="page">Next</button>
</form>

<form method="GET" name="FormPage">
    <select name="page" style="float: left;" onChange="document.forms['FormPage'].submit()"> 
    <?php
        for($i = 1, $size = ceil($row['0']/25); $i <= $size; $i++)
            echo "<option ".($page == $i ? "selected " : "")."value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: why not css?  you are using inline style

Comment: I might as well do it you are right, i said that because i am least good with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figure it out. I just had to add `<span style="float:left;"> </span>` in each of my forms and delete `style` inside of them.